# Does DS-5 FVP support CacheData View?

Tags: caching, arm, cortex-a, ds-5

### DS-5 Debugger Cache View

I want to dump cache lines in Cortex-A9 MPCore with DS-5 FVP, but no data in *Cache View* windows found.

Then I google for it, and found the official document:

[ARM® DS-5™ Debugger User Guide : 10.18 Cache Data view](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0446r/ris1395317606041.html)

below is what I found in My DS-5(picture):

[DTSL Configuration Editor dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuR16.png)

And I have also tried to enter `cache list` in command line, result below:

```
ERROR(TAB115): No cache awareness for core "ARM_Cortex-A9MP_1"
```

#### Question

How to get the cache view on DS-5, or MUST do with a DStream ?

Comment: Firstly, what version of DS-5? (I recall the cache awareness being rubbish in older versions.) Secondly, are you running the FVP with cache state modelling turned on? [The documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0837g/rob1396282410765.html) suggests the supplied FVP builds don't even support it. Lastly I'm just puzzled at where you imagine a software model has a physical JTAG port to plug a DStream into ;)

Comment: Version=5.20.2 Ultimate ;  You mean the FVP can be configured ? but I only found some FVP models to select. the last one :0 I mean DSTREAM + Board.